# How to setup kibana Single sign on with keycloak

Tags: kibana, keycloak, elasticsearch-opendistro

Kibana Single Sign-On with OpenID and Keycloak. I have configured the the setup by following the opendistro documentation.
https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/security-configuration/openid-connect/

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:0.7.0
    container_name: odfe-elasticsearch
    environment:
      -  discovery.type=single-node     
      -  bootstrap.memory_lock=true # along with the memlock settings below, disables swapping
      -  "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" # minimum and maximum Java heap size, recommend setting both to 50% of system RAM
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - odfe-data1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./elastisearch-opendistro-sec/config.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins/opendistro_security/securityconfig/config.yml
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600 # required for Performance Analyzer
    networks:
      - odfe-net
  kibana:
    image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch-kibana:0.7.0
    container_name: odfe-kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    volumes:
      - ./kibana-opendistro-sec/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: https://odfe-elasticsearch:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: https://odfe-elasticsearch:9200
    networks:
      - odfe-net
volumes:
  odfe-data1:
networks:
  odfe-net:
```

keycloak-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      volumes:
        - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
        MYSQL_USER: keycloak
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      networks:
        - odfe-net
  keycloak:
      image: jboss/keycloak
      environment:
        DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
        DB_ADDR: mysql
        DB_DATABASE: keycloak
        DB_USER: keycloak
        DB_PASSWORD: password
        KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
        KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      networks:
        - odfe-net
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - mysql
volumes:
  mysql_data:
networks:
  odfe-net:
```

config.yml

```
opendistro_security:
  dynamic:
    authc:
      basic_internal_auth_domain:
        enabled: true
        order: 0
        http_authenticator:
          type: basic
          challenge: false
        authentication_backend:
          type: internal
      openid_auth_domain:
        enabled: true
        order: 1
        http_authenticator:
          type: openid
          challenge: false
        config:
          subject_key: preferred_username
          roles_key: roles
          openid_connect_url: http://172.29.0.3:8080/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration
        authentication_backend:
          type: noop
```

kibana.yml

```
opendistro_security.auth.type: "openid"
opendistro_security.openid.connect_url: "http://172.29.0.3:8080/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration"
opendistro_security.openid.client_id: "kibana-sso"
opendistro_security.openid.client_secret: "841d796a-bc3a-4cc8-9fb9-bed6221f66b4"


elasticsearch.url: "https://odfe-elasticsearch:9200"
elasticsearch.username: "kibanaserver"
elasticsearch.password: "kibanaserver"
elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: none
elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: ["Authorization", "security_tenant"]
```

The open Id connect endpoint needs to be specified in kibana.yml and config.yml file.

When I use localhost in the openid connect endpoint url 
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration
I get the following error.

```
"Client request error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080"}
odfe-kibana      | /usr/share/kibana/plugins/opendistro_security/lib/auth/types/openid/OpenId.js:151
odfe-kibana      |                 throw new Error('Failed when trying to obtain the endpoints from your IdP');
```

The error got resolved after following the solution given in this link:
[ECONNREFUSED nodeJS with express inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063822/econnrefused-nodejs-with-express-inside-docker-container)

kibana is running at localhost:5601 but, when I try to load the page in the browser I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Below are the logs:

```
odfe-kibana      | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-06-27T23:00:54Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: https://odfe-elasticsearch:9200/"}
odfe-kibana      | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-06-27T23:00:54Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
odfe-elasticsearch | [2019-06-27T23:00:54,613][INFO ][c.a.o.e.p.h.c.PerformanceAnalyzerConfigAction] [8EPY7C_] PerformanceAnalyzer Enabled: true
odfe-elasticsearch | Registering Handler
odfe-elasticsearch | [2019-06-27T23:00:54,687][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [8EPY7C_] initialized
odfe-elasticsearch | [2019-06-27T23:00:54,687][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [8EPY7C_] starting ...
odfe-elasticsearch | [2019-06-27T23:00:54,918][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [8EPY7C_] publish_address {172.29.0.5:9300}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9300}
odfe-elasticsearch | [2019-06-27T23:00:54,967][INFO ][c.a.o.s.c.IndexBaseConfigurationRepository] [8EPY7C_] Check if .opendistro_security index exists ...
odfe-elasticsearch | [2019-06-27T23:00:55,064][INFO ][c.a.o.s.h.OpenDistroSecurityHttpServerTransport] [8EPY7C_] publish_address {172.29.0.5:9200}, bound_addresses {0.0.0.0:9200}
odfe-elasticsearch | [2019-06-27T23:00:55,067][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [8EPY7C_] started
odfe-elasticsearch | [2019-06-27T23:00:55,070][INFO ][c.a.o.s.OpenDistroSecurityPlugin] [8EPY7C_] 4 Open Distro Security modules loaded so far: [Module [type=AUDITLOG, implementing class=com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.auditlog.impl.AuditLogImpl], Module [type=MULTITENANCY, implementing class=com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.configuration.PrivilegesInterceptorImpl], Module [type=DLSFLS, implementing class=com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.configuration.OpenDistroSecurityFlsDlsIndexSearcherWrapper], Module [type=REST_MANAGEMENT_API, implementing class=com.amazon.opendistroforelasticsearch.security.dlic.rest.api.OpenDistroSecurityRestApiActions]]
odfe-elasticsearch | [2019-06-27T23:00:55,558][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [8EPY7C_] recovered [2] indices into cluster_state
odfe-elasticsearch | [2019-06-27T23:00:56,394][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [8EPY7C_] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.opendistro_security][0]] ...]).
odfe-elasticsearch | [2019-06-27T23:00:56,684][INFO ][c.a.o.s.c.IndexBaseConfigurationRepository] [8EPY7C_] Node '8EPY7C_' initialized
odfe-kibana      | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-06-27T23:00:57Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@6.5.4","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from red to green - Ready","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at https://odfe-elasticsearch:9200/."}
odfe-kibana      | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-06-27T23:00:57Z","tags":["listening","info"],"pid":1,"message":"Server running at http://localhost:5601"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use "localhost" in conjunction with Keycloak and Docker, especially if you're running Docker for Mac.

The error you're seeing (connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080") means that Kibana is attempting to connect to itself (its own Docker container) on port 8080.  This seems confusing, but "localhost" has a very specific meaning on each machine - and don't forget, each Docker container is its own machine.  Instead, you want it to connect out of the docker network to your host machine on port 8080.

To do this, I'd recommend using "127.0.0.1.xip.io" (check out xip.io for what this is) as your domain name.  You may need to also configure this address using "extra_hosts" in your docker-compose file.