# Access docker container from another docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, apollo, apollo-server

I have following services in separate containers as you can see in the docker-composer.yml file. I'm unable to link one service to another. I'm trying to access service, built on node exposing on port 7100, in gms-api-gateway on network bridge. But connection is being refused.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  gms-api-gateway:
    restart: always
    links:
      - gms-customers
    networks:
      - backend
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./gms-api-gateway
    depends_on:
      - gms-customers
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
    volumes:
      - './gms-api-gateway:/opt/app'
    environment:
      # - NODE_ENV=localhost
      - NODE_PORT=7000
      - NODE_HOST=http://localhost
      - GMS_CUSTOMERS_NODE_HOST=http://gms-customers:7100
  gms-customers:
    restart: always
    networks:
      - backend
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./gms-customers
    depends_on:
      - customers-db
    ports:
      - 7100:7100
    volumes:
      - './gms-customers:/opt/app'
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=localhost
      - NODE_PORT=7100
      - CUSTOMER_DB_URI=postgres://postgres:password@customers-db/customersdb

  customers-db:
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=customersdb
    image: 'postgres:12'
    ports:
      - '0.0.0.0:5433:5432'

networks:
  backend:
    driver: 'bridge'
```

gms-api-gateway

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import {ApolloServer} from 'apollo-server';
import {ApolloGateway} from '@apollo/gateway';

const port = process.env.NODE_PORT || 7000;
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  serviceList: [
    {
      name: 'customers',
      url: `${process.env.GMS_CUSTOMERS_NODE_HOST}/graphql`
    }
  ],

  // Experimental: Enabling this enables the query plan view in Playground.
  __exposeQueryPlanExperimental: false
});

(async () => {
  const {schema, executor} = await gateway.load();
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    executor
  });

  server.listen(port, (): void =>
    console.log(
      `API Gateway is now running on ${process.env.NODE_HOST}:${port}/graphql`
    )
  );
})();
```

Now, the service gms-api-gateway is trying to access graphql schema from another service called gms-customers. But in logs I'm receiving this

```
Encountered error when loading customers at http://gms-customers:7100/graphql: request to http://gms-customers:7100/graphql failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:7100
```

Both services are at the same network. Inside gms-api-gateway `ping gms-customers` works! Someone faced the same issue?

Comment: Sometimes this can be a timing problem, is your port up before you make the request? Maybe you need to setup a delay/waiter before you reach out for the service.

Comment: where exactly should i setup a delay? I'm `await`ing to load schema.@BlackNetworkBit

Comment: Checkout https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ to see how to setup such a order.

Comment: You may have to set your gateway application to listen to things from outside its own container.  Does changing the listen call to `server.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => ...)` help?

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't fix the issue. @DavidMaze

Comment: Ok, so inside api-gateway container i ran `wget http://gms-customers:7100/graphql` i got this `Resolving gms-customers (gms-customers)... 172.18.0.7
Connecting to gms-customers (gms-customers)|172.18.0.7|:7100... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2020-03-04 22:14:54 ERROR 400: Bad Request.` @DavidMaze @BlackNetworkBit

Comment: @SherazAli can you show your code or tel us what gms-customers is

Comment: its in the docker-composer.yml. It's actually the name of service. And this is how i pinged `const hosts = [
  'gms-customers',
  'gms-customers:7100',
  'http://gms-customers:7100',
  'google.com'
];
hosts.forEach(function(host) {
  ping.sys.probe(host, function(isAlive: any) {
    const msg = isAlive
      ? 'host ' + host + ' is alive'
      : 'host ' + host + ' is dead';
    console.log(msg);
  });
});`

Comment: Yes I know its a service but can you show the code? Your error is saying that you're connected to the particular ip but its not handling your request

Comment: Ah I see here is the code https://gist.github.com/sherazali123/93677076cff18d1c0acfa4b20d30caa0

Comment: Just figuring out a way to make host an absolute url in docker-composer.xml

Comment: Finally, i figured out why requests wasn't working. I was running command `tsc -p . && nodemon dist/index.js` i Just changed it to `dist/index.js` and it works!! Thank you all for your help